# is print a function in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

In python everything is an object and you can pass it around easily.

So I can do :

```
>> def b():
   ....print "b"
>> a = b
>> a()
   b
```

But if  I do

```
a = print
```

I get `SyntaxError` . Why so ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Python 2.x, print is a statement **not** a function. In 2.6+ you can enable it to be a function within a given module using `from __future__ import print_function`. In Python 3.x it is a function that can be passed around.

Comment: the future statement is explicit. It won't break any code because it affects only code that expects it in the same module

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - thank you - I always confuse that with "A future statement typed at an interactive interpreter prompt will take effect for the rest of the interpreter session."

Answer (score 6):

In python2, `print` is a statement. If you do `from __future__ import print_function`, you can do as you described. In python3, what you tried works without any imports, since print was made a function.

This is covered in [PEP3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are correct.  `print` is a statement, not a function in python2.x.  What you have will work on python3.  The only thing that I have to add is that if you want something that will work on python2 and python3, you can pass around `sys.stdout.write`.  This doesn't write a newline (unlike `print`) -- it acts like any other file object.

Answer (score 3):

`print` is not a function in pre 3.x python. It doesn't even look like one, you don't need to *call* it by `(params)`